# Can't find a bug in my small JS code (for loop and a function inside)

Tags: javascript

Here is my code. Console says :Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

```
var em = document.getElementsByClassName("rot");

    for (var i = 0, len = em.length; i < len; i++) {
        em[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.classList.toggle("rotate");
        }
    }
```

Comment: When in doubt, count parenthesis and curlybraces, and within minutes you'd notice the missing closing of the event listener.

Comment: This is a good time to [learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820).

Comment: I did and I didn't notice. But now I see what I've missed. It's so frustrating.

Comment: Use the console. You would have seen `SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` and even in which line the error occurs. See my previous comment.

Comment: thanks for the article Felix. Yes I saw this in console and then I went and removed the curlybrace, but than other error occurred so I went and did something else and back and forth and back and forth. But yes I will approach this problem differently next time and I will sure read the article you shared. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this (you were missing the close parenthesis and semicolon to close the addEventListener)

```
var em = document.getElementsByClassName("rot");

for (var i = 0, len = em.length; i < len; i++) {
    em[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("rotate");
    });
}
```

Comment: Why? Do you like playing the "spot the difference" game? Is it the indentation? *edit:* Ah. Though the semicolon is not required to make it work.

Comment: @FelixKling it was pretty short code, but I added an explanation.

Comment: It doesn't matter. *"Try this `<code>`"* answers are rarely helpful. Thanks for updating!